# Hide/Show div on click and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a search form which is hidden and when we click the search icon that form appears and when user click away or scrolls the search form hides.

Comment: Make research about `:focus` state in CSS and basic events such as `click` in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .onclick event in js and change display and visibility property in a function. For example:

```
document.getElementById("searchIcon").onclick = searchFunction
function searchFunction(){
   const search = document.getElementById("searchForm");
   search.style.display = "block";
   search.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Of course, by default it should be hidden. But display: none is not nesseccary, depends on your website.

Comment: it  is working but i just want that "this ia a part of div" to be hide again when we click somewhere on<body> or when we scroll

Comment: add a function which checks whether your search part is displayed or no. If yes - hide it. In this case `const search` should be a global variable(outside a function).

Comment: `document.body.onclick = hideFunct` `oncscroll = hideFunct` `function hideFunct(){ if(search.style.display === "block"){ search.style.display = "none"; search.style.visibility = "hidden";}}`

Comment: '$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#search").fadeOut();
  });
  $("body").click(function(){
    $("#search").fadeOut();
  });
  $("#btn").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#search").fadeToggle();
  });
}); ' this jquery worked for m

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Whenever you click on the image, "This is part of the div" appears in Red.
Basically, you use Javascript to set/remove the `hidden` Attribute every time the user clicks the `<img>` item. Additionally, you change the `<img>`'s `onclick` Attribute to the opposite function(`show_div()==>hide_div();hide_div()==>show_div()`):

```js
//see html on where to put this
show_div=function(){//Executed when the div ISN'T shown and the user clicks on the <img> tag
document.getElementById("search_div").removeAttribute("hidden");
document.getElementById("search_icon").setAttribute("onclick","hide_div()");}
hide_div=function(){//Executed when the div ISN'T shown and the user clicks on the <img> tag
document.getElementById("search_div").setAttribute("hidden","true");
document.getElementById("search_icon").setAttribute("onclick","show_div()");}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<img height="32" width="32" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3917/3917754.png" onclick="show_div()" id="search_icon">
<div id="search_div" hidden="true">
<font size=7 color="Red">This is part of the div</font>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">//put the Javascript part here when copy-pasting this code
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You might want to take a look at the "hidden" attribute and the "click" event.

Comment: it  is working but i just want that "this ia a part of div" to be hide again when we click somewhere on<body> or when we scroll

Comment: @TheDST Add a new `<script>` Tag somewhere into the html(anywhere after the first `<script>` tag, but inside the `<body>` tag) with the following content: `document.body.onclick=hide_div;onscroll=hide_div;`. Dont forget the `type="text/javascript"` attribute. That should do it. Tell me if it works.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#search").fadeOut();
  });
  $("body").click(function(){
    $("#search").fadeOut();
  });
  $("#btn").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#search").fadeToggle();
  });
}); this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

i am using **`addEventListener`** to get if any click is happened you can use any section of the on the place of document to make it work for that particular section. i.e: header

and then i am using **`classList.toggle`** to add and remove a particular class from the search input box.
you can add CSS as per your need.

```js
 var searchbox=document.querySelector("#search-bar");
        var searchIcon=document.querySelector(".search-icon");
        
        document.addEventListener("click",searchBar);
        function searchBar(){
         searchbox.classList.toggle("search-bar");
        }
```

```css
   .search-bar{
         display:none;
        }
```

```html
   <div>
        
        <input class="search-bar" id="search-bar"  type="text" placeholder="search..."> 
        <i class="search-icon">&#128269; </i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This jquery function worked for me

'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#search").fadeOut();
  });
  $("body").click(function(){
    $("#search").fadeOut();
  });
  $("#btn").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#search").fadeToggle();
  });
}); '
```

with this function when user scrolls the page the search bar will hide

below is a javascript version

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    document.getElementById("search").style.display = "none";
  });
  document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("search").style.display = "none";
  });
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var search = document.getElementById("search");
    if (search.style.display === "none") {
      search.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      search.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)